# Добавление зависимости androidx

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

Файл *build.gradle* выглядит следующим образом:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.recyclerviewexample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
}
```

Но в результате сборки ошибки:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\Xu\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar\45f296cd7466b0137ad2b0b5868320be\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\Xu\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar\45f296cd7466b0137ad2b0b5868320be\res\values\values.xml
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(1304, 5) error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
D:\Android Projects\RecyclerViewExample\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml
Error:(11) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(7) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Error:(11) resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\Android Projects\RecyclerViewExample\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(231) resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(231) resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 7s
Information:13 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

При этом, если блок `dependencies` выглядит так:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

то сборка проходит успешно. Как добавить зависимость `androidx` в проект? Версия Android Studio - 3.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview)

> New Project If you create a new project using the androidx-packaged
> dependencies (as opposed to refactoring an existing project with the
> Android Studio tool), your new project needs to target API level 28,
> and you will need to add the following lines to your gradle.properties
> file:
>
> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true

требуется выставить `targetSdkVersion` как минимум 28 и добавить явное разрешение на использование либ из `androidx` пакета в файле `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что было нужно)